# Oracle - Hierarchical Query with Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have just started to learn hierarchical queries to solve problems. Most of the examples available are based on the condition that there is a specific parent and you can connect to it using prior.

However, I have a table structure like below where Column A is parent of Column B and Column B is parent of Column C.

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SaaS | A Cloud | Test 1 |
| SaaS | A Cloud | Test 2 |
| SaaS | A Cloud | Test 3 |
| SaaS | B Cloud | Test 1 |
| SaaS | B Cloud | Test 2 |
| SaaS | C Cloud | Test 1 |

Based on the above table, I would like to see if there are any techniques to achieve the below results.

**SaaS** (Top-Level)

- A Cloud (Level 2)

  - Test 1 (Level 3)
  - Test 2
  - Test 3
- B Cloud

  - Test 1
  - Test 2
- C Cloud

I am unable to use the starts with due to multiple columns and no specified way of identifying Column_A as the distinct parent.

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1 (COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B,COLUMN_C) AS
SELECT 'SaaS','A Cloud','Test 1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SaaS','A Cloud','Test 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SaaS','A Cloud','Test 3' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SaaS','B Cloud','Test 1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SaaS','B Cloud','Test 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SaaS','C Cloud','Test 1' FROM DUAL


select TAB1.*,LEVEL from TAB1
START WITH COLUMN_A='SaaS'
connect by prior  COLUMN_B = COLUMN_A AND COLUMN_C= COLUMN_B
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: It's perfectly possible to walk the graph the way you want, but what exactly do you want as a result? If it's a simple String, then what are those bullets? Or do you want something like HTML with tags? Please elaborate.

Comment: I am trying to display this data in a tree region on Oracle Apex.
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it  what are you looking for:

```
with newTab (ParentCol,ChildCol) as (
select distinct  null  ParentCol, Column_A ChildCol from Tab1 where Column_A='SaaS'
union all
select distinct Column_A ParentCol,Column_B ChildCol from Tab1
union all
select distinct Column_B,Column_C from Tab1),
cte (ParentCol,ChildCol,lvl) as (
select ParentCol, ChildCol , 1 as lvl from newTab where ParentCol is null
union all 
select  nt.ParentCol, nt.ChildCol , (cte.lvl+ 1) as lvl from  newTab nt inner join cte on nt.ParentCol=cte.ChildCol)
select * from cte
```

Output:

```
|PARENTCOL|CHILDCOL|LVL|
| -       |SaaS    |1  |
|SaaS     |A Cloud |2  |
|SaaS     |C Cloud |2  |
|SaaS     |B Cloud |2  |
|A Cloud  |Test 3  |3  |
|A Cloud  |Test 2  |3  |
|A Cloud  |Test 1  |3  |
|C Cloud  |Test 1  |3  |
|B Cloud  |Test 1  |3  |
|B Cloud  |Test 2  |3  |
```

Comment: You sir are amazing. Thank you very much. I learnt something new today. I had hit a recursive error during actual implementation but was able to figure that out when I looked at the logic and removed the redundancy at level 3.

Comment: That's great. Best wishes.